# How do I access the user's password from LDAP in a LdapUserDetailsMapper using spring security?

Tags: passwords, ldap, spring-security

We are using spring security in our web application based on spring MVC.

We are doing authentication using LDAP module of spring security which is working properly. Now I need to get the user password from LDAP for saving in the database.

For this I am using this in my code.

```
    public class PersonContextMapper implements UserDetailsContextMapper {

    public UserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations ctx, String username, Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
    Person.Essence p = new Person.Essence(ctx);

    p.setUsername(username);
    p.setAuthorities(authorities);

        Object passwordValue = ctx.getObjectAttribute("userPassword");

    return p.createUserDetails();

    }

    public void mapUserToContext(UserDetails user, DirContextAdapter ctx) {
    Assert.isInstanceOf(Person.class, user, "UserDetails must be a Person instance");

    Person p = (Person) user;
    p.populateContext(ctx);
    }
}
```

But I am not getting the any value for the password. Its always null.

Please help.

PS. My authentication is successful. It means password entered in the login form is matches properly with the password stored in the LDAP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be that the authentication state of the connection does not have permission to read the value of the `userPassword` attribute. Most often, applications issue a BIND request to the directory server, including appropriate controls as necessary. The password is included in the BIND request and the directory server changes the authentication state of the connection upon successful completion of the BIND request. In any case, the value of the `userPassword` attribute is encrypted or hashed more often than not, and applications have no need to read the value.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. How do I change the authentication state of the connection to have permission to read the value of the userPassword attribute? Our legacy code can read password attribute and store in the database. Its only after we modified it to use spring security, we are not able to read password.,

Comment: The authentication state is set by the BIND request. In addition to the authentication identity established on the connection by the BIND, there might be additional access controls in place preventing the client from reading the attribute. If your new application and your legacy application use the same authentication identity (the values passed to the BIND request), unless some other protection precludes it, then the client should be able to read the value of the userPassword attribute. Ask your directory server administrator about "access control instructions" (ACIs).

Comment: `..and applications have no need to read the value.` Not always strictly true. Reading the hash can be useful when you're performing authentication of a user alongside the system using ldap. A different use case is Automount which (can) use ldap to store credentials to be used when connecting/mounting. Of course, that requires encrypted creds instead of hashing but still, it's a use...

Comment: In that case, applications that depend on the format of a cryptographic hash are subject to failure because all servers do not create a hash in the same way, for instance, salts can be of varying lengths and placements.